# Cron: Diaplay the commands run by cron scheduler using awk

Tags: bash, awk, cron

I'm writing a script to get a list of only the commands from my crontab.
My input data so far looks like this:

```bash
$  crontab -l | grep -i --color -v '^#' | awk '$0 ~ /^*\/[0-9]{1,20}|\*+/'
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/bash msmtp-queue -r 
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/env bash /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/env bash ~/bin/checkMail
00 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/bash ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
* */3 * * * /usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

#### Outcome

Print everything after either '/usr/bin/env bash' or '/usr/local/bin/bash' or '* */3 * * *'

```bash
msmtp-queue -r 
offlineimap-fetch
checkMail
lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

### Tried

I tried starting from the end of file ($NF) and printing everything up until the first forward slash but I just got syntax errors with where to put the brackets:

```bash
$ crontab -l | grep -i --color -v '^#' | \
awk -F'/' '{ if ($0 ~ /^*\/[0-9]{1,20}|\*+/) for(i=NF;i>0;i--) { if ( sub(/\//, "", $i) { print $i} } }'
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ($0 ~ /^*\/[0-9]{1,20}|\*+/) for(i=NF;i>0;i--) { if ( sub(/\//, "", $i) { print $i} } }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                              ^ syntax error
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't really want the output in your question and instead want the output shown in the currently accepted answer then all you need is:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ]* ){5}//' file
/usr/local/bin/bash msmtp-queue -r
/usr/bin/env bash /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
/usr/bin/env bash ~/bin/checkMail
/usr/local/bin/bash ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
/usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

The above requires a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD sed. With any POSIX sed you could do  `sed 's/\([^ ]* \)\{5\}//' file` instead or with any POSIX awk `awk '{sub(/([^ ]* ){5}/,"")}1' file`.

Comment: Once again @Ed-Morton, you have proven to be the King of AWK :)

Answer (score 1):

> get a list of only the commands from my crontab

I would just jettison 5 first fields, let `file.txt` content be

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/bash msmtp-queue -r 
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/env bash /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/env bash ~/bin/checkMail
00 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/bash ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
* */3 * * * /usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.lo
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ]"}{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5="";sub(/^ */,"");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
/usr/local/bin/bash msmtp-queue -r
/usr/bin/env bash /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
/usr/bin/env bash ~/bin/checkMail
/usr/local/bin/bash ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
/usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.lo
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) is single space. I do not use default FS as it would cause changing tab characters to space characters to space and compressing spaces (2 or more consecutive spaces into single space). For each line I set 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th field to empty string, then use `sub` to shave off leading spaces, then `print` such altered line.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Comment: I like the approach, however, I have a PATH= statement in my crontab and the above outputs all commented files, plus: `* MAILTO="" ; [[ -f ~/.calcurse/caldav/lock ]] && rm -f ~/.calcurse/caldav/lock ; PATH=/Library/...`

Comment: I put in a `grep -v '^#'` into the pipe before the awk and the output came out perfect!

Comment: Code ameloriated as suggested in comments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

> Print everything after either '/usr/bin/env bash' or
> '/usr/local/bin/bash' or '* */3 * * *'

and given the format of the examples, you can split on the different patterns and check if there are at least 2 parts.

If `file` contains the example data:

```
awk '
{
  n = split($0,a, /(^\* \*\/3 \* \* \*|\/usr\/local\/bin\/bash|\/usr\/bin\/env[[:space:]]+bash)[[:space:]]+/)
  if (n > 1) {
    print a[2]
  }
}
' file
```

Output

```
msmtp-queue -r 
/Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
~/bin/checkMail
~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
/usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

Comment: This is great. It has the desired outcome although I think @Daweo answer of discarding the cron schedule part from the first 5 fields in the first place is more future proof as it doesn't need a regex that makes path matches which may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` (if applicable)

```
$ sed s'/.*\(bin\/\|\/env \)\?bash \|.*\* //' input_file
msmtp-queue -r
/Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
~/bin/checkMail
~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
/usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f- index.lock --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F"bash|env bash|env" '!/^#/ {print $2}' <(crontab -l)
 msmtp-queue -r 
 /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
 ~/bin/checkMail
 ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
 rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to account for potential tabs :

```
mawk 'BEGIN { OFS=_;__=_="[^"(_=" \\t]")"*["_; gsub("...",_,_); FS="^"(_)__ } NF=NF'

 or

{n,g}awk 'BEGIN { OFS=_;FS="^("(_="[^"(_=" \\t]")"*["_)"){5}" } NF=NF'
```

—————

```
/usr/local/bin/bash msmtp-queue -r 
/usr/bin/env bash /Users/tonybarganski/bin/offlineimap-fetch
/usr/bin/env bash ~/bin/checkMail
/usr/local/bin/bash ~/bin/lbdb-fetchaddress-daily
/usr/bin/env rsync -auv -f"- index.lock" --exclude={'Macintosh HD','MyArchive'} ~/mnt/ ~/.Backup/mnt/ > ~/crypto-vols-backup.log
```

if tabs are no concern then even simpler :

```
{n,g}awk 'NF=NF' FS='^([^ ]+[ ]+){5}' OFS=
```